# SQL Server 2016 - System_Versioned table - Re-create existing table with meaningful SysStartTime and SysEndTime fields

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, temporal, temporal-database

We have two tables, `Events` and `EventsLog`. The `Events` table is shown below

[image]

The `EventsLog` table is used to keep a history of changes made to the `Events` table via a trigger on UPDATE in the `Events` table.

Since Temporal tables was added to SQL 2016, we now want to use system_versioning to keep a log of our changes to the `Events` table.

We have setup a new `EventsTemporal` table to migrate over the existing data and the `EventsTemporal_History` table is working nicely, logging historical entries from `EventsTemporal`

However, we cannot override the `SysStartTime` and `SysEndTime`. Currently we can only apply `default` into these fields when performing an INSERT statement.

---

The question is, using any method possible, can we override the `SysStartTime` and `SysEndTime` fields so we can INSERT meaningful `datetime2`'s into them, to make use of the `EventsTemporal_History` table?

This is currently how the `EventsTemporal` table looks. Notice the `SysStartTime` field, we want to be able to populate these fields with our own 'timestamp' and not use SQLs default.

[image]

Ideally we want to be able to populate these fields like the below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable SYSTEM_VERSIONING on EventsTemporal.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE EventsTemporal SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );
   ```
2. Update EventsTmeporal as normal table.

   ```
   UPDATE D
   SET D.SysStartDate = S.EventDate
   FROM dbo.EventsTemporal AS D
   INNER JOIN dbo.Events AS S 
     ON D.EventId = S.EventId;
   ```
3. Enable SYSTEM_VERSIONING on EventTemporal;

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.EventsTemporal ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime);

   ALTER TABLE dbo.EventsTemporal ALTER COLUMN SysStartTime ADD HIDDEN;
   ALTER TABLE dbo.EventsTemporal ALTER COLUMN SysEndTime ADD HIDDEN;

   ALTER TABLE dbo.EventsTemporal
       SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EventsTemporal_History ) );
   ```

Comment: Hi @qxg, this is great and I appreciate your effort! The History table, as mentioned, is fine and you're right the SysEndTime's are populated with sensible 'correct' data and not 9999-xxx. The problem is with the `SysStartTime`s in the main `EventsTemporal` table

Comment: @Skaterhaz sorry, I made some mistake. The principal is the same,  modifying period data before enabling temporal. You can try is yourself while I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I don't have a SQL Server 2016 by hand now. If above script doesn't work, try to re-create EventsTemporal completely with manually added SysStartTime/SysEndTime column. You can check current EventsTemporal creation script for related columns.

Comment: Thanks @qxg, this is essentially what we're doing right now, turning off the versioning, but this is *after* we have created the table with GENERATE_ALWAYS turned on for the SysxxxTime columns. It seems you can't turn off the GENERATE_ALWAYS once it's declared, rendering the versioning futile for this task. You're right though, we can just re-create the tables and then apply versioning and GENERATE_ALWAYS. So thanks very much!